# List of device labels returned by MediaDevices.enumerateDevices

Tags: javascript, video, navigator, mediadevices

Calling [navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices) in the browser returns `MediaDeviceInfo` for each media device present on the client. This includes `deviceId`, `groupId`, `kind` and `label`.

Filtering by `kind === 'videoinput'` I'm able to get a list of video cameras available.

However, the `label` for devices on different clients seem to vary wildly.  For example, the camera on a MacBook Pro may have a label of "FaceTime HD Camera (05ac:8514)", while the label on a Pixel 3 main camera is "camera2 0, facing back".

Is there a list of which labels are returned by common client (mobile devices, laptops or USB cameras) so that I can parse them in my code & present a consistent name to the end user?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?